# openmp : check if nested parallesim

Tags: c++, openmp

Assume I have a method that multiplies two `std::vector` :

```
double multiply(std::vector<double> const& a, std::vector<double> const& b){
    double tmp(0);
    /*here I could easily do a parallelization with*/
    /*#pragma omp parallel loop for*/
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        tmp += a[i]*b[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

If I set in this function the pragma macro, a call to `multiply(...)` will run
on all threads.

Now assume that somewehere else I want to do many vector multiplication :

```
void many_multiplication(std::vector<double>* a, std::vector<double>* b, unsigned int N){
    /*here I could easily do a parallelization with*/
    /*#pragma omp parallel loop for*/
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<N;j++){
            multiply(a[i],b[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I could also do the parallelization the same way. But this will lead to
unwanted nested parallelism.

How can I check that if `multiply(..)` is called within a parallel region,
then the `pragma` macro of `multiply(...)` is "turn off". And if it's called
from a non-parallel region, then it's "turn on".

Comment: Note also a small typo in your example code: your `multiple` function adds the values from its input `vector`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nested parallelism is **disabled** by default, unless enabled specificially by setting `OMP_NESTED` to `true` or by calling `omp_set_nested(1);` (§2.3.2 of the [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf)) Explicitly modifying the settings for nesting as suggested by Avi Ginsburg is a bad idea. Instead, you should use conditional parallel execution based on the level of nesting:

```
double multiply(std::vector<double> const& a, std::vector<double> const& b){
    double tmp(0);
    int active_levels = omp_get_active_level();
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:tmp) if(active_level < 1)
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        tmp += a[i]+b[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

`omp_get_active_level()` returns the number of active parallel regions that enclose the thread at the moment the call is made. It returns `0` if called from outside a parallel region or with inactive outer region(s). Thanks to the `if(active_level < 1)` clause, the parallel region will only be activated, i.e. run in parallel, if it is not enclosed in an active region, regardless of the setting for nesting.

If your compiler does not support OpenMP 3.0 or higher (e.g. with any version of MS Visual C/C++ Compiler), then `omp_in_parallel()` call can be used instead:

```
double multiply(std::vector<double> const& a, std::vector<double> const& b){
    double tmp(0);
    int in_parallel = omp_in_parallel();
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:tmp) if(in_parallel == 0)
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        tmp += a[i]+b[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

`omp_in_parallel()` returns non-zero if at least one enclosing parallel region is active, but does not provide information about the depth of nesting, i.e. is a bit less flexible.

In any case, writing such code is a bad practice. You should simply leave the parallel regions as they are and allow the end user choose whether nested parallelism should be enabled or not.

Comment: Interesting. From what version of OMP does `omp_get_active_level` exist? I usually use VS (stuck at 2.0) and I know it doesn't exist there.

Comment: Individual control over the different levels of parallelism was introduced in OpenMP 3.0. With pre-3.0 compilers one could use `omp_in_parallel()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add the pragma to both functions. You can turn the [nested parallelism](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/omp_005fset_005fnested.html) on and off with `omp_set_nested(int val)` (zero for off, non-zero for on).

So, if you wanted nested parallelism on in your program in general, but off for the `many_multiplication` function, you would implement `many_multiplication` as follows:

```
void many_multiplication(std::vector<double>* a, std::vector<double>* b, unsigned int N){
    omp_set_nested(0);
    #pragma omp parallel loop for
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<N;j++){
            multiply(a[i],b[j]);
        }
    }
    omp_set_nested(1);
}
```

Comment: thx. but if I understand your answer and if I never want nested parallelism, I could just add the pragama to both functions and when `multiply` is called from outside a parallel region, it will then parallelize the loop for but when it's called within a parallel region it won't parallelize the loop.

Comment: Yes, but if you never wanted nested parallelism, you can define the environment variable OMP_NESTED as true instead.

Comment: Sorry, I meant OMP_NESTED should be defined as false to disable nested parallelism. If undefined, false is the default.

Comment: Calling `omp_set_nested(1);` at the end enables *unconditionally* nesting, no matter what the value of `OMP_NESTED` and therefore what the expectation of the end user might be.