# Nested paralleled regions OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

What does it mean in OpenMP that

> Nested parallel regions are serialized by default

Does it mean threads do it continuously? I also can not underestend this part:

```
A throw executed inside a parallel region must cause execution to resume within
the dynamic extent of the same structured block, and it must be caught by the
same thread that threw the exception.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-parallel.html) (scroll down to "17.1 Nested parallelism", by default a nested parallel region will *not* be parallelized, thus run sequentially. Nested thread creation is possible using either `OMP_NESTED=true` (as environment variable) or `omp_set_nested(1)` (in your code).

**EDIT:** also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520326/openmp-check-if-nested-parallesim/31522514#31522514) to a similar question.

Comment: what is  nested parallel region

Comment: A nested parallel region is a parallel region inside another parallel region, just like any other nested structure. The website I linked has some examples, and searching the Internet for "openmp nested parallel region" gives plenty of examples and explanations as well.