# How to balance the thread number in nested case when using OpenMP?

Tags: openmp

This fabulous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520326/openmp-check-if-nested-parallesim/31522514#31522514) teaches me a lot, but I still have a question. For the following code:

```
double multiply(std::vector<double> const& a, std::vector<double> const& b){
    double tmp(0);
    int active_levels = omp_get_active_level();
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:tmp) if(active_level < 1)
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        tmp += a[i]+b[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

If `multiply()` is called from another parallel part:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    multiply(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

Because the outer loop iteration depends on `count` variable, if `count` is a big number, it is reasonable. But if `count` is only `1` and our server is a multiple-core machine(e.g., has `512` cores), then the `multiply()` function only generate `1` thread. So in this case, the server is under-utilized. BTW, the answer also mentioned:

> In any case, writing such code is a bad practice. You should simply leave the parallel regions as they are and allow the end user choose whether nested parallelism should be enabled or not.

So how to balance the thread number in nested case when using `OpenMP`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using OpenMP tasks (`omp taskloop` within one parallel section and an intermediate `omp single`). This allows you to flexibly use the threads in OpenMP on different nesting levels instead of manually defining numbers of threads for each level or oversubscribing OS threads.

However this comes at increased scheduling costs. At the end of the day, there is no perfect solution that will always do best. Instead you will have to keep measuring and analyzing your performance on practical inputs.