# Programmatically disable nested parallelism in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, nested-loops

I am facing the same request as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520326/openmp-check-if-nested-parallesim), i.e. I want to parallelize an "inner" loop in a first subroutine, which may or may not not be called from an "outer" parallelized loop in another subroutine. In the case of nested calls, I want to disable the inner parallelization, and keep only the outer one. The solution provided in the above link does not seem to work. Here is an illustrative code:

```
program test
  !$ use omp_lib
  !$ write(*,'(A,I0)') "Running OpenMP version ",openmp_version
  write (*,'(A)') 'Direct call to basic:'
  call basic(1)
  write (*,'(A)') 'Iterative call to basic:'
  call iterative()
end program test
!
subroutine basic(i)
  !$ use omp_lib
  integer(kind=4), intent(in) :: i
  integer(kind=4) :: j,level
  !$ level = OMP_GET_ACTIVE_LEVEL()
  !$ write(*,'(A,I0)') "  Basic parallelization level is ",level
  !$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(i) PRIVATE(j) IF(level<1)
  !$OMP DO
  do j=1,3
    write (*,'(A,2I3,A,I0)') "  i,j = ",i,j," done by thread ",omp_get_thread_num()
  enddo
  !$OMP END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
end subroutine basic
!
subroutine iterative()
  !$ use omp_lib
  integer(kind=4) :: i
  !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(i)
  !$OMP DO
  do i=1,2
    write (*,'(2(A,I0))') "  Iterative executes iteration ",i," from thread ",omp_get_thread_num()
    call basic(i)
  enddo
  !$OMP END DO
  !$OMP END PARALLEL
end subroutine iterative
```

AFAIU, when "iterative" is invoked, I face nested OMP loops. Since OMP nesting is disabled here, the "inner" loop is expected to be executed by the calling thread (and only the calling thread): this is what I want.

Unfortunately when I execute the code using gfortran 9.2.0 I get:

```
> gfortran -fopenmp test.f90 -o test && ./test
Running OpenMP version 201511
Direct call to basic:
  Basic parallelization level is 0
  i,j =   1  2 done by thread 1
  i,j =   1  3 done by thread 2
  i,j =   1  1 done by thread 0
Iterative call to basic:
  Iterative executes iteration 2 from thread 1
  Basic parallelization level is 1
  i,j =   2  1 done by thread 0
  i,j =   2  2 done by thread 0
  i,j =   2  3 done by thread 0
  Iterative executes iteration 1 from thread 0
  Basic parallelization level is 1
  i,j =   1  1 done by thread 0
  i,j =   1  2 done by thread 0
  i,j =   1  3 done by thread 0
```

When "basic" is called directly, it is correctly parallelized (threads 0, 1 and 2). When "iterative" is called, its main loop is well parallelized (threads 0 and 1). Then I expect each "basic" loop to be executed by each calling thread (0 and 1). Unfortunately, they are ALL executed by thread 0!

If I edit the code to remove the "OMP PARALLEL IF(condition)" clause (but keep the "OMP DO") from the "basic" subroutine, the "iterative" call works correctly (but I loose the parallelization when calling "basic" directly). In other words, when "condition" is false, the "OMP PARALLEL IF(condition)" clause does not behave as if it was completely absent.

I have the same problem with ifort 18.0.3.222, OpenMP 201611.

What is happening?

Comment: Did you try without the the `if()` clause? Normally the nested parallelism is disabled and that should just work by default

Comment: I just tried, this does not help.

Comment: My guess is that the function `omp_get_thread_num()` misleads you: it prints the rank in the innermost enclosing `parallel` region, which in the case of the nested one, only has 1 thread. So although there are different threads calling the function, they all get a thread id 0 as they all are in their individual "single-thread parallel region"

Comment: @Gilles that was indeed the problem. I implemented a real use case with significant execution times, and the parallelization behaves as expected. Sorry for the confusion!